# How to benchmark few lines of code in nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I read this down and up: http://nim-lang.org/docs/times.html

But still cannot figure the simple thing: how to get time in ms twice, once before my code, and again after my code runs, and then print the difference?

I tried their example:

```
var t0 = cpuTime()
sleep(300)
echo "CPU time [s] ", cpuTime() - t0
```

But this prints something meaningless:

```
CPU time [s] 4.200000000000005e-05
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you plan to perform a lot of measurements, the best approach is to create a re-usable helper template, abstracting away the timing code:

```
import times, os, strutils

template benchmark(benchmarkName: string, code: untyped) =
  block:
    let t0 = epochTime()
    code
    let elapsed = epochTime() - t0
    let elapsedStr = elapsed.formatFloat(format = ffDecimal, precision = 3)
    echo "CPU Time [", benchmarkName, "] ", elapsedStr, "s"

benchmark "my benchmark":
  sleep 300
```

This will print out

```
CPU Time [my benchmark] 0.305s
```

If you need more comprehensive data about the performance of all of the code included in your project, Nim offers a special build mode, which instruments the compiled code with profiling probes. You can find more about it here:

http://nim-lang.org/docs/estp.html

Lastly, since Nim generates C code with C function names that directly correspond to their Nim counterparts, you can use any C profiler with Nim programs.

Comment: Ey, i didn't know this profile. Nim is full of secrets.

Answer (score 5):

`cpuTime` only calculates the time the CPU actually spends on the process, at least on Linux. So the entire sleeping time doesn't count. You can use `epochTime` instead, which is the actual UNIX timestamp with subsecond accuracy.